# MYSQL - GROUP BY 2 COLUMN ORDER BY CREATION DATE

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, max, multiple-columns

I'm trying to get all results of my table with a GROUP BY on 2 columns and get the last insertions.

"Prices" table :

[image]

My Request :

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.*
FROM prices p 
JOIN (
SELECT MAX(created_at) as "last_created" 
FROM prices
WHERE station_id = 27210003
GROUP BY station_id, fuel_id) as sub 
ON sub.last_created = p.created_at
WHERE p.station_id = 27210003
GROUP BY p.station_id, p.fuel_id
```

Results are 3 lines but wrong line because not last created in my DB -_-'

[image]

Please help me !!! >_<'

Thx

Answer (score 2):

Since you're selecting a specific `station_id` in the `WHERE` clause, you don't need to include that in `GROUP BY`.

The subquery has to return the columns you're grouping on, and then you have to include them in the `ON` clause.

And you don't need `GROUP BY` in the outer query, since the `JOIN` should ensure that there's just one row for each `fuel_id` (unless there are duplicate `created_at` for the same `fuel_id` and `station_id`).

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.*
FROM prices p 
JOIN (
    SELECT fuel_id, MAX(created_at) as "last_created" 
    FROM prices
    WHERE station_id = 27210003
    GROUP BY fuel_id) as sub 
ON sub.last_created = p.created_at AND sub.fuel_id = p.fuel_id
WHERE p.station_id = 27210003
```

Comment: Seems unlikely that there could be more than one, but there we go.

Comment: If there can, you need to use more than just `GROUP BY fuel_id`, you need another column to `MAX` or `MIN` with to select the one you want.